# Pegar elemento interno da Div ao lado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar em um botão, o conteúdo da `div` ao lado fique editável. 
 
Melhor visualizando o código:

```
<div id="nome" class="container">
    <div class="col-10">
        <p class="editar" contenteditable="false">Digite o nome</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button>Editar</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Sobrenome" class="container">
        <div class="col-10">
            <p class="editar" contenteditable="false">Digite o Sobrenome</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button>Editar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Atualmente o jQuery está assim, mas ao clicar no botão são selecionados ambos os conteúdos.

```
$("button").click(function() {      
    if ($("div > .editar").attr("contenteditable") == "false") { 
        $("div > .editar").attr("contenteditable", "true");
        $("div > .editar").focus().text(""); 
        $("div > .editar").addClass("selecionado"); 
        $(this).text("Concluído"); 
    } else { 
        $("div > .editar").attr("contenteditable", "false"); 
        $("div > .editar").blur(); 
        $("div > .editar").removeClass("selecionado"); 
        $(this).text("Editar"); 

        if ($("div > .editar").is(":empty")) { 
            $("div > .editar").text("Digite o nome"); 
        }; 
    };
});
```

Não estou encontrando um modo para usar o .closest que acho que seria uma possível salvação para atribuir o botão clicado ao elemento da div ao lado, já que ambas tem o mesmo pai (a #nome ou #sobrenome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, e aos que estão tendo a mesma dificuldade, eis a solução que encontrei.

```
$(this).siblings()
```

Usado para pegar a div irmã do elemento e depois entrando no paragrafo.

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

O problema que você está enfrentando é mais de semântica do HTML do que a função do `click` com *JQuery*. Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<div id="nome" class="container">
<div class="col-10">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputs" value="Fulano" disabled/>
</div>
<div id="Sobrenome" class="container">
<div class="col-10">
    <label>Sobrenome</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputs" value="da Silva" disabled/>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
    <button id="editar">Editar</button>
</div>

$("#editar").on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.inputs').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Segue [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/acdj3qqc/) funcional

Comment: Hmm, muito boa sua ideia! Mas pretendo separar em grandes grupos para futuras mudanças e preciso manter um botão para cada input(no caso).